# Cannot uninstall python/pip on raspberry pi 3 b+

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pip, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a raspberry pi 3B+. I want to upgrade the python from 2.7 to 3.6.

I downloaded the python 3.6 extracted and made it, However it got installed in the `/usr/local/bin`.

I tried to make it again this time by specifying `./configure --prefix=/usr` prefix however the make gave a traceback error.

I also tried `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2` which helps in changing versions of python.

However, after doing so, my pip is not working now. 
I have the following files in `/usr/local/bin:pip,pip2.7,pip3,pip3.5,pip3.6`.

I tried removing pip so that i can reinstall it using `sudo apt-get remove python-pip` but it gives the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin $ sudo apt-get remove python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-all-dev python-all python-all-dev python-keyring
  python-keyrings.alt python-secretstorage python-wheel
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python-pip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 671 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 29, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
(Reading database ... 138007 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-pip (9.0.1-2+rpt2) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which suggests that apt_pkg (or some problem with apt-get). 
when i do `pip --version` , i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I just want to have python 3.6 and 2.7(since i have already installed libraries on 2.7) with functional pip.

Comment: You really should **not** edit the preinstalled OS python... I would encourage trying pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install miniconda for ARM and get Python and all important packages at once ?

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
sudo md5sum Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
sudo /bin/bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
sudo reboot -h now
```

Comment: Because conda will use a lot of space and space is limited on raspberry pi . Doesnt conda install other packages too which will not be used ? Moreover , it took me 30 min to setup anaconda on an i5 processor with 8 gb ram . Install conda on raspberry pi will take forever with space wastage

Comment: I didn't have problems doing that in my Raspberry. It was simple, fast and after that, just `pip install` what I wanted. Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project

Comment: how much storage did it take ? i am on 8GB card only

Comment: My SD Card too, 8GB. Miniconda has 29.9 MB only. Plus Python libraries.

Comment: That's great . Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: However i dont think miniconda will solve my problem though . I need to install opencv,cmake,dlib,face_recognition libraries that will require pip

Comment: Trust me, you can do all of this. Even install and run Deep Learning models, as Tensorflow, or face recognition, OpenCV. There are tutorials everywhere.

Comment: Okay ! i will try and let you know ! Thanks

Comment: I installed miniconda on the default path(in root) as per your code above rather than as specified in https://www.hackster.io/lbtinglb/install-opencv-through-miniconda-in-second-on-rasberry-pi-3-4eec27 and now i cannot access it

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't aware that most linux distros come shipped with python2 AND python3. By typing `python` and `pip` you will use your operating systems python2 and pip2 version.
What you probably want is using `python3` and `pip3` instead.

Something like "upgrading" from python2 to python3 is not possible because it's a fundamental difference and they are incompatible. This is why you have both installed.

Uninstalling or upgrading your systems python interpreter is a terrible bad idea, because your system needs them. For professional usage you should think about version control again, but for your first (and second) steps in python it's totally fine to use the preinstalled python interpreter of your OS.
Solutions like pyenv or virtualenv are very powerfull tools, but you probably don't want to start with it.